# Работа с объектом series в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Есть столбец , мне нужны только значения по ключу 'name'.

```
df['key_skills']
0                                                       []
1        [{'name': 'Git'}, {'name': 'SQL'}, {'name': 'Т...
2        [{'name': 'SQL'}, {'name': 'Linux'}, {'name': ...
3        [{'name': 'Пользователь ПК'}, {'name': 'Работа...
4        [{'name': 'MS Dos'}, {'name': 'Диагностика ПК'...
                               ...           
Name: key_skills, Length: 69656, dtype: object
```

Написал код:

```
def get_key_skills(new_key_skills):
  asd = new_key_skills.replace("{'name': ", "").replace("}", "")
  return (asd)
```

и добавил новый столбец:

```
df['new_key_skills'] = df['key_skills'].apply(get_key_skills)
```

Вопрос можно как-то сделать более по питоновски?Или как работать в Pandas c строкой в которой список словарей.Спасибо

Comment: у вас вопрос об одом, а решение о другом - вопрос про значения ТОЛЬКО по ключу name, а решение - все значения ключей. так что же вам нужно?

Comment: В моем случае , ключи всех словарей 'name'. Извините если не точно сформулировал.

Answer (score 0):

Предположим, есть датафрейм:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["[{'name':'SQL'}, {'name': 'python'}, {'name' : 'applied magic']"],
                                ["[{'skill':'SQL'}, {'name': 'oracle'}, {'virtue' : 'fishing']"]], columns = ["key_skills"])
```

```
                                                        key_skills
0  [{'name':'SQL'}, {'name': 'python'}, {'name' : 'applied magic']
1     [{'skill':'SQL'}, {'name': 'oracle'}, {'virtue' : 'fishing']
```

можно решить вопрос с помощью метода findall:

1. если нужны значения только по ключу 'name':

```
df['new_key_skills'] = df["key_skills"].str.findall(r"'name'\s?:\s?'([^']+)'")
```

получаем df:

```
                                                        key_skills                new_key_skills
0  [{'name':'SQL'}, {'name': 'python'}, {'name' : 'applied magic']  [SQL, python, applied magic]
1     [{'skill':'SQL'}, {'name': 'oracle'}, {'virtue' : 'fishing']                      [oracle]
```

Если нужно получить просто все значения для любых ключей, то:

```
df['new_key_skills'] = df["key_skills"].str.findall(r":\s?'([^']+)'")
```

получаем:

```
                                                        key_skills                new_key_skills
0  [{'name':'SQL'}, {'name': 'python'}, {'name' : 'applied magic']  [SQL, python, applied magic]
1     [{'skill':'SQL'}, {'name': 'oracle'}, {'virtue' : 'fishing']        [SQL, oracle, fishing]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Отлично.